# xiar rc splines.a splines.o realloc(): invalid pointer

Tags: linux, ubuntu, spline, intel-oneapi

I'm going to install Splines using Intel oneAPI compiler in Ubuntu, but i have some trouble problems. However, if i install it using gnu, i can do it. So, is the problem due to incorrect intel oneAPI installation, or something else? Hoping you guys can give me some advices. Thank you!!!!!!!!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbYrq.jpg)
And, this is my shell script.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzkXG.jpg)

Hoping you guys can give me some advices. Thank you!!!!!!!

Comment: Firstly, installing stuff isn't a programming question for SO, consider superuser.com instead. Further, include output as text, not as images hosted on some external volatile site. Being new here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: As your query is related to installation issues, Please raise a query in [oneAPI Registration, Download, Licensing and Installation](https://community.intel.com/t5/oneAPI-Registration-Download/bd-p/registration-download-licensing-instal)!